# Knowing the futility of discounting in continuing problems, how can we say discounting has no role in control problems with function approximation?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, function-approximation, sutton-barto, discount-factor, continuous-tasks

Sutton-Barto (Section 10.4, page 254):

[image]

Based on the futility of discounting in continuing problems, how can we conclude that discounting has no role to play in control problems with function approximation?